# Angular $location.path() not getting base tag path

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the base url for my application so that my service can send http request dynamically to the back end.

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,$location){
       var baseUrl = $location.protocol() +"://"+ $location.host()+":"+$location.port()+$location.path();
       console.log($location.path());
       $http.get(baseUrl+"person").success(data){
         $scope.data = data; 
      };
    });
```

I set base tag in the index.html like `<base href="/helloworld/">`

When I try to `console.log("path: "+$location.path())`, it only shows `path: /`. So it doesn't get the `/helloworld` value.
So I am wondering why this happen. And is anyway we can retrieve the base tag value beside using `$location.absUrl()`. Thank you advanced!

Comment: @Erazihel Yes I did, still return `url:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<base href="/helloworld/">` does not have a relationship with `$location.path()`. `$location.path()` takes the current path, what you see in the address bar, parses it and returns the values to you.

**`<base>` (From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp))**

The  tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.

For example:

```
<head>
   <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
   <img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman">
   <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</body>
```

In the above example, the browser will look for `stickman.gif` at `http://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif`.

---

**`$location.path()` [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js)**

This code only looks at the current url and does not take into account the base element.

```
  path: locationGetterSetter('$$path', function(path) {
    path = path !== null ? path.toString() : '';
    return path.charAt(0) == '/' ? path : '/' + path;
  }),
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I think I have to use `$location.absUrl()` to get the url to phrase then.